# sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: store_comment.post_id(Implementing Comment functionality.)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am getting *sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: store_comment.post_id*.Please find the below error details.

```
 Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'ShaileshShop.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Checking comment post is happening or not:YES
Product in comment post: Black Skater Dress
Check Check Check
Internal Server Error: /details/3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: store_comment.post_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/djangoshaileshdurga/ShaileshEcomm/store/views.py", line 295, in post
    new_comment.save()
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1384, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: store_comment.post_id
[02/Nov/2020 14:42:46] "POST /details/3 HTTP/1.1" 500 155444
/Users/shaileshyadaav/djangoshaileshdurga/ShaileshEcomm/store/models/comment.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/PycharmProjects/first/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/djangoshaileshdurga/ShaileshEcomm/store/models/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .comment import Comment
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/djangoshaileshdurga/ShaileshEcomm/store/models/comment.py", line 14
    post=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='comment',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null)
```

so to resolve this error I have used **null=True** in my models.py file as shown below.

After which I am not getting any error however data is not getting saved and it's redirecting to the same page(http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/10) with the form filling data.(Please check the attached image).

```
from django.db import models
# need to import Category model
from .product import Product


class Comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='comment',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email=models.EmailField()
    body=models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #now order we can define.

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-created',)

    #now let me take str if any person wants to display comment object.
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Commented by {} on {}'.format(self.name,self.post)
```

views.py

```
    from store.forms import CommentForm
class Details(View):
    def get(self,request,myid):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=myid)
        print('Checking product value in details:',product)
        comments= product.comment.filter(active=True)
        form = CommentForm()
        
        return render(request, 'details.html', {'product':product,'form':form,'comments':comments})

    def post(self,request,myid):
        print('Checking comment post is happening or not:YES')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=myid)
        print('Product in comment post:',product)  # here i am getting product
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # print('Checking Form valid:',form )
            print('Check Check Check')
            new_comment = form.save(commit = False)
            
            new_comment.product = product  ##trying to associated post for which user commented
            # print('Pk:',new_comment)
            new_comment.save()
            

            return render(request, 'details.html', {'product':product, 'form':form , })
```

details.html

```html
 <!--#######adding comment section below to post######-->
                                {% with comments.count as comment_count %}
                                <h2>{{comments_count}} Comment{{comments_count|pluralize}}</h2>
                                {%endwith%}

                                <!--#now lets display comments:)-->
                                {%if comments%}
                                {%for comment in comments%}
                                <p id='ch'> comment {{forloop.counter}} by {{comment.name}} on {{comment.created}}</p>
                                <div class="commentbody">{{comment.body|linebreaks}}</div>
                                <hr>
                                {%endfor%}

                                {%else%}
                                <p>There is no Comment Yet!!You are the first to comment on this..</p>
                                {%endif%}
                                <!--###Now if cooment is Submitted then we need to display form to end user.-->

                                {%if csubmit%}
                                <p>Hey!,Your comment has submitted successfully.To submit another comment please refresh
                                    browser! </p>
                                {%else%}
                                <!--          <p id="submit1">Please submit your comment.</p>-->
                                <form   method="post">
                                    {{form.as_p}}
                                    {%csrf_token%}
                                    <input  type="submit" name="" class='btn btn-lg
                                    btn-success' value="Submit Your Comment">
                                </form>
                                {%endif%}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't put null value inside `post=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='comment',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)`

try to remove `null=True` and add a `default=Product.objects.all().first()` value to the field or `blank=True`.